# Redirecionamento de resultado de soma em servlet JSP

Tags: java, jsp, servlet

Preciso mostrar o resultado de uma soma em uma pagina redirecionada, tentei um "setAttribute" depois do "Redirect" mas não funciona. O valor da soma teria que ir para um "input" na próxima página, ou em um "`<h1>`" simples. A parte do "request", onde ocorre o início da soma está tudo ok.

Tenho o seguinte metodo:

```
@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    try (PrintWriter out = response.getWriter()) {
        int soma = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("a")) + Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("b"));

        response.sendRedirect("resultado.jsp");
        response.getContentType();
        request.setAttribute("result", soma);
    }
}
```

E o seguinte codigo na pagina .jsp:

```html
<h1> Resultado da soma: <input type="number" name="result"> </h1>
```

Comment: Acho que basta apenas você receber na página o atributo "result", <input type="number" name="result" value="{$result}">

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O seu método doGet(), precisa ser reajustado.

Segue uma possível alteração:

```
@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {

        int a = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("a"));
        int b = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("b"));
        int soma = a + b;

        request.setAttribute("result", soma);
        request.getRequestDispatcher("resultado.jsp")
               .forward(request, response);
}
```

> Usando o sendRedirect(), estás mudando o fluxo a nível de cliente. Isto é, estás pedindo para o navegador fazer uma **nova requisição** para resultado.jsp. Desta forma você perde os dados: a, b e soma.

> Usando o getRequestDispatcher(), estás mudando o fluxo a nível de servidor (forward/bypass) para resultado.jsp **transferindo** a request (contendo o atributo result armazenando a soma) e response sem o cliente nem notar. Tipo, shhhh na migué... não conta nada pra ele [cliente].

O resultado.jsp precisa ser reajustado.

Segue uma possível alteração:

`<input type="number" name="result" value="${result}" />`